# How i get all stuff from different branch in git

Tags: git, version-control

I have two branches `branchA` and `branchB`

branchB I have made from master branch

Now my branch A has many commits done. But I want to have all the stuff from `branchB`. and ignore all mofification , new files etc from `branch A`. I don't want to merge but just make the current snapshot of `branchB` on `A`

Answer (score 3):

```
git reset --hard branchB
```

This will blow away the complete history of the current branch and replace it with the commit specified.

*Use with caution*

Comment: Just in sake of clarity: it won't *replace* the history (the history will stay there for some time), it will just move the branch head

Comment: just to be clear, u mean to say that if have 20 previous commits on branchA , then will they stay there or not. because i want that in case i need to go back then i can go back to previous commits

Comment: @user24: They will be unreferenced.  If you want a backup, create another branch from `branchA` before doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you want to take a backup you can take a copy from the first branch first, then overwrite the second branch

```
git checkout branchA
git branch backupA
git reset --hard branchB
```

And if you want to delete the old `branchB`

```
git branch -d branchB #( -D ) for force delete, but I prefer the small `d` first
```

The result now would be `branchA` which contains the content of the old `branchB` and a `backupA` which contains the content of the old `branchA`